# tabs click url change and load view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tabs

My application is MVC based. I have tabs and on click event of tab a particular tab's partial view is loaded without loading the whole page so the url remains the same. see www.dadabhagwan.tv left side tabs.

So, now I want the same page to be loaded but with url change. I have achieved the same using window.history.pushState().  But if on opening a new window and paste this new url, I am not able to load the view.

Comment: On initialization of the application you need to check the URL and route it correctly to the right page.

Comment: I did the same and I am now able to redirect to the page. But now wants to open up the particular tab. So, trying the same.